# Website wait before get a data from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

Hi I'm making a web site with React.Js, Node.Js(Express).

```js
 <Link onClick={event => passwordCheck(event)} to={isRegisteredID ? "/" : "/register"} >
   <button type="submit">Register</button>
 </Link>
```

I want to execute the "to" method in Link after the passwordCheck function.

How can I do this?

Currently, I am building my backend with Express, and exchange data between the client and server using Socket.io

Comment: Import `useHistory` hook and add this to the bottom of `passwordCheck` function `history.push(isRegisteredID ? "/" : "/register")`

Comment: Complexify your `onClick` function by doing the check inside followed by `history.push` to the page and remove the `to` props.

Comment: Really thanks for your help. I was able to fix it because of your help.